# public static class variable that has const tag, but mutable from within the class

Tags: c++

I realize this can be done with a static getter function, but I was curious if there was a keyword that would make this possible.

something like:

`static const [keyword] int totalInstances;`

Comment: C++ can't do it, you would have to use something like C# properties and only implement the getters.

Comment: There are no keywords you could use but you could use a wrapper class or a reference to fake this.

Comment: @NathanOliver hm im interested if you could provide an example

Comment: Here is an example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ff24a11feaede68.  It would not stop someone from casting away the `const` though and modifying the actual value.